# Servers needed for Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

What is the server needed to launch an ember.js sample application in windows? What is the exact procedure for the same?

Answer (score 1):

Ember-CLI comes with a development server which can be started with the command `ember serve`.

There is a quickstart guide on emberjs.com to help you with this: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/getting-started/quick-start/